# How to run a custom maven goal in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

I use a declarative Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline{
    agent : any
    environment {
        APPSCAN_CLOUD = credentials("APPSCAN_CLOUD")
        APPSCAN_CLOUD_ID = credentials("APPSCAN_CLOUD_ID")
        MAVEN_SETTINGS = credentials("MAVEN_SETTINGS")
    }
    tools {
        maven "maven-3.6.3"
        jdk "jdk8"
        git "Default"
    }
    stages{
        stage("AppScan"){
            steps{
                echo "======== here is the show ========"
                sh "./run_appscan.sh"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which triggers a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run the appscan security check
mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS \
-DskipTests \
-DappId= $APPSCAN_CLOUD_ID \
-DappscanKey=$APPSCAN_CLOUD_USR \
-DappscanSecret=$APPSCAN_CLOUD_PSW \
com.hcl.security:appscan-maven-plugin:analyze
```

When I run the script locally, it behaves as expected. However in the Jenkins pipeline I get the error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "`****`". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.

> -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException: Unknown lifecycle phase "`****`". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:248)

I tried to put all commands on one line and put the goad first before the `-D` parameters. No change in result.

Standard goals like `compile` or `package` or `site` do work as expected.

It looks like the goal is masked out somehow. What do I miss?

Comment: Difficult .. are you sure the plugin is available on Jenkins?

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: Does one of your $VARIABLEs expand in an unexpected way, e.g. containing spaces?

Comment: That was one of my suspicions too. I don’t think so, but I’ll investigate further. I also will check if I can attach the plugin to a regular phase.

Comment: Is in your script the space `-DappId= $APPSCAN_CLOUD_ID`  between `appId=HER`? If so you should remove it...